# Weird intermittent crash on synchronous start of an NSOperation on main thread

Tags: ios, swift, nsoperation

I have a system here that renders itself in bits that get stitched together. Sometimes those bits are rendered in an background threads, but sometimes when latency of feedback is really important those bits are rendered synchronously on the main thread.

This code is called on the main thread, in a method named `createPatchView`, and `patchView.createRenderingOperation()` returns a subclass of `NSOperation` that does the rendering. The async version works fine, the operation queue picks up the job and handles it in the background. But the other branch where we want to render it *right now* is giving me intermittent crashes.

```
// Figure out when to render it
if async {
    // Add the patch rendering job to the tile rendering queue.
    tiledView.renderingQueue.addOperation(patchView.createRenderingOperation())
} else {
    // Render and install the patch right now on the main thread for maximum responsiveness.
    patchView.createRenderingOperation().start() // <-- CRASHES HERE
}
```

Here's the crash detail:

```
Signal: SIGSEGV: SEGV_ACCERR at 0x10
Reason: objc_msgSend() selector name: observationInfo
```

[image: crash stack]

And I've yet to replicate this with the debugger attached, which is frustrating, but the crash logs are clearly coming in.

So, all on the main thread, the render operation is created. Then we call `start()` on that operation to do it right now. So now before it gets to any of *my* code in the operations `main()` method, some internal key value observation handler kicks off and calls `observationInfo` on some internal object that's somehow invalid? At this point it feels like I'm trying to understand the inner workings of a black box that doesn't work anymore.

Have I missed some pitfall of running an `NSOperation` outside of an `NSOperationQueue`?

**UPDATE:**
Is it bad form to call `patchView.createRenderingOperation().main()` instead? I suppose in this case, I don't need to keep track of the status of the operation in a thread safe way. I just need it to do it's work and continue execution from there. In theory, this should avoid whatever is crashing nested inside the logic of the `start()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refactor the code out of `main` and put it somewhere else.  Call that code from your operation's `main` and whenever you want it to happen.

Comment: I guess this is the answer. But when you have an operation who's job it is to render stuff, it seemed prudent to simply use it but with different timing. Why it sometimes crashes, and sometimes it's fine, I wish I knew. Debugging crashes that happen _inside_ someone else compiled code sucks.

Comment: NSOperation is coupled to NSOperationQueue -- it was not designed to be used in the way you want. Even if you got something to work, it isn't future proof.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding the operation to the main queue. Will that also crash?

```
if async { 
    ....
} else {
    OperationQueue.main.addOperation(patchView.createRenderingOperation())
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's how this code started, actually. It turns out "do it now" and "do it on the main queue" have pretty big timing differences. They both happen on the main thread, but when you add it the main queue the job may not start for an indeterminate amount of time.

Comment: But does it crash when submitted to the main queue?

Comment: No, I don't think so. Which leads me to believe manually starting an `NSOperation` outside of a queue should be avoided. Which I suppose makes sense.

Comment: It depends, perhaps your start() method relies on the current context to be inside an operation queue. Just get rid of those pieces. If you try with an empty operation, call the start() method and it should run just fine.

Comment: Actually, shouldn't you be calling main() instead??

Comment: And it does work 99% of the time, but then it doesn't and everything explodes. And yeah I can call `main()` instead which I'm doing now. But I feel like calling `start()` should have worked 100% of the time, too.